# macOS crash CGFontIsBitmapOnly

Tags: swift, macos

I recently noticed that the macOS app I am working on has quite a lot of crashes that have to do something with fonts.
I have no idea where to look for the problems. Never seen it myself, but the crash logs comming in are very similar.

I have tried googling with no luck. Maybe someone here can point me to some other source of information to help me fix this bug.

Here are some of the crash logs. (Included only the crashing threads, because other threads show nothing usefull at all).

https://gist.github.com/karlis/01222e4cfa061eefc38965ea6dfeefd6

Comment: Is it reproduceable and have you filed a radar for this?  It would help for SO if you could post the code that's crashing as well as the stack trace.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith, no, I haven't. I asked the same question in apple developer forum. I assumed this had to do something with the code of my application.

Comment: It's probably wise to assume it's your code.  However, if you have a reproducible situation that you think should work I would file a radar or use one of your TSI's.   Otherwise, not posting code here is going to reduce the likelihood that anyone can help.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith The problem is with the crashes not being reproducible myself. I just see that there are a few almost each day.

The logs don't show anything useful for me and I can't find the piece of code that's failing.

This is more like a try to find others with the same problem. Maybe they have solved it somehow and can give some advice. Not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Our app is having the same crashes. On analysing these reports in Fabric, we figured out that it's happening because of low memory situations. At the time of crash user's free memory is around 1%. I did a stress testing on my app in low memory situation and I was able to reproduce it a few times (but never in debug mode).